# XSLT transformation for money

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need XSLT transformation for money.

In input XML data are prices as numbers:

```
<prices>
    <price>1234</price>
    <price>1234.5</price>
</prices>
```

I need to have output XML after XSLT transformation as follows (Czech format):

```
<prices>
    <price>1 234,-</price>
    <price>1 234,50</price>
</prices>
```

Can it be done using XSLT? Thank you very much.

**Edit:** I'm using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? The former is notoriously bad at doing such string conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation** (in both versions of XSLT):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:decimal-format
    name="Cz1"
    grouping-separator=" "
    decimal-separator="_"/>
<xsl:decimal-format
    name="Cz2"
    grouping-separator=" "
    decimal-separator=","/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="price/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '# ##0,00', 'Cz2')"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="price/text()[. = floor(.)]" priority="3">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '# ##0', 'Cz1')"/>
      <xsl:text>,-</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<prices>
    <price>1234</price>
    <price>1234.5</price>
</prices>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<prices>
   <price>1 234,-</price>
   <price>1 234,50</price>
</prices>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render numbers as locale-specific money Strings if your stylesheet has an instance of a `NumberFormat` object.  You can get one using `java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale locale).getCurrencyInstance()`.  Then add it to your stylesheet and off you go.

Comment: He hasn't specified using Java, though. Chances are he is, but it's not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-number, as in

```
  <xsl:decimal-format
    name="f1"
    grouping-separator=" "
    decimal-separator=","/>

  <xsl:template match="price">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '# ###0,00', 'f1')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am not sure however how to get the ",-" that way.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in another function that simply substitutes `,00` with `-`. Slightly dirty, but it should work.